# Does it matter which way units are facing?

Tags: wargroove

When I move a unit in Wargroove, its sprite will face left or right depending on the direction I last moved. Does the direction a unit is facing have an effect on gameplay? IE: Can a unit be ambushed if it's facing the wrong direction?